# Laravel 6 seeding one to many relationship using model factories

Tags: laravel, faker, factories

I have the following model factories:

```
 $factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
   return [
      'first_name' => $faker->firstName,
      'last_name'  => $faker->lastName,
      'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
      'password' => 'secret', 
      'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
  ];
});

$factory->define(App\Order::class, function (Faker $faker) {
     return [
       'tax_id'  => 3,
       'total' => 0.00,
       'order_type' => 'Invoice'
    ];
});

$factory->define(App\OrderItem::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
       'product_id' => 19,
       'product_name'  => 'Free product',
       'quantity' => 1,
       'item_price' => 0.00,
    ];
});

$factory->afterCreating(App\User::class, function ($user, $faker) {
     $user->orders()->save(factory(App\Order::class)->make());
});

$factory->afterMaking(App\Order::class, function ($order, $faker) {
     $order->orderItems()->save(factory(App\OrderItem::class)->make());
});
```

When I call `factory(App\User::class, 2)->create();` I get error:

```
 Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'order_id' cannot be null")
```

Why aren't these call back methods working, any advice appreciated?

Comment: Is there any reason you are using `make()` instead of `create()` for the `order` and `orderItems`? You can't save `orderItems` into the database for an order that has not been saved to the database yet.

Comment: @Remul because they both have foreign keys. Order has foreign key for user and if I use `create` I get integrity constrain violation.

Comment: Perfect explaination on seeding relations using factories. https://medium.com/risan/seeding-table-with-relationships-in-laravel-c1e18355013f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of mixing the factory and eloquent, I think it would be cleaner to just use the factory so you can use the `afterCreating` / `afterMaking` hooks properly:

```
$factory->afterCreating(App\User::class, function ($user, $faker) {
    factory(App\Order::class)->create(['user_id' => $user->id]);
});

$factory->afterCreating(App\Order::class, function ($order, $faker) {
    factory(App\OrderItem::class)->create(['order_id' => $order->id]);
});
```